# Javascript to extract certain string from data

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a regex to extract first occurrence of a string from a data.

For example my data is like :

```
SFASDŞŞVMA SAD SADAS MYABCD12345678911TY ISIADABCD12345678911SAD
```

I need to extract `ABCD123456789` from this data.

I need to find first occurrence of string always starts with `ABCD` and has total length of 13.

How can I achieve this with using regex?

I tried regex `/^ABCD(\w{9})$/gm` which didn't work for me.

Comment: Use `ABCD\w{9}` and omit the `/g` global flag. You also don't need the `/m` using this pattern https://regex101.com/r/lD8jZh/1

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html, https://regex101.com/r/GrEXLd/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/ABCD\w{9}/g` with `match()` to get the result from first *index*:

```js
var str = "SFASDŞŞVMA SAD SADAS MYABCD12345678911TY ISIADABCD12345678911SAD"

console.log(str.match(/ABCD\w{9}/g)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `^ABCD(\w{9})$` does not match because you use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

Note that if you want a full match only, you don't need a capturing group `(\w{9})`

You can omit those anchors, and if you want a single match from the string you can also omit the `/g` global flag and the `/m` multiline flag.

```
ABCD\w{9}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD8jZh/1/)

```js
const regex = /ABCD\w{9}/;
const str = `SFASDŞŞVMA SAD SADAS MYABCD12345678911TY ISIADABCD12345678911SAD`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[0])
```